# ESMTP MailEnable with PHP

Tags: windows, php, smtp, email

I am running a windows server (windows 7) with IIS 7.  ESMTP MailEnable is running on port 25.  I am also running apache and php on the server.  When I use php's `mail()` it returns false indicating that it can't connect to the outgoing SMTP server (at least I believe that's what it means).  I can tell that MailEnable is running because when I run

```
>telnet localhost 25
```

the response is

```
220 WDC1358.home ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 5.10-- ready at 06/18/11 20:06:43
```

I am at a loss for why this is not working with php.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log as well as MailEnable SMTP log (MainEnable Administrator -> Servers -> localhost -> Connectors -> SMTP -> Logs -> Debug)? MailEnable log should tell the possible reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to enable Mail Relay for local address.

> **Allow relay for privileged IP ranges**. Allows people with certain IP
>   addresses to send email through the
>   server. If the IP addresses of persons
>   who are able to send email out through
>   the server is known, use this option.
>   DO NOT select this option if the list
>   of IP addresses is unknown, as this
>   may inadvertently allow everyone
>   access. This option is usually
>   required to allow sending through the
>   server from a web server or web page.

MainEnable Administrator -> Servers -> localhost -> Connectors -> SMTP -> Properties -> Relay -> Enable Mail Relay -> Allow relay for privileged IP ranges. Add your IP there (simple "127.0.0.1" should work fine).